# How to handle Window inset in android?

Tags: android

How to correctly handle the top and bottom system window inset in android?

Can someone provide example?

I have used `android:fitsSystemWindows=”true”` in layout but it still does not work.

How to get `getSystemWindowInsetBottom` and `getSystemWindowInsetTop` to add padding.

[Example] Image from https://chris.banes.dev/2019/04/12/insets-listeners-to-layouts/
[Example]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBdvN.png

My Code `@BindView(R.id.slideViewPager)
ViewPager viewPager;

```
@BindView(R.id.layoutDots)
LinearLayout dotsLayout;

@BindView(R.id.btn_next)
Button btn_next;

private ImageView[] dots;
private int[] layouts;

private int mCurrentPage;

@Inject
PreferenceUtil preferenceUtil;

Animation animation;

int topPadding, bottomPadding;

View view;


//  @BindView(R.id.activity_walkthrough)
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addTransparentStatusBar();

    Injector.component().inject(this);

    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_walkthrough);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_walkthrough);

    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view, (OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (v, insets) -> {
        view = relativeLayout.getRootView();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            topPadding = view.getRootWindowInsets().getSystemWindowInsetTop();
            bottomPadding = view.getRootWindowInsets().getSystemWindowInsetBottom();
        }
        return null;
    });


    layouts = new int[]{
            R.layout.fragment_walkthorugh1,
            R.layout.fragment_walkthorugh2,
            R.layout.fragment_walkthorugh3};

    // adding bottom dots
    addBottomDots(0);

    setupViewPager();

    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.up);
    btn_next.startAnimation(animation);

}

private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {

    if (dotsLayout != null) {
        dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
    }

    dots = new ImageView[layouts.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i] = new ImageView(this);
        dots[i].setPadding(0, 0, 5, 0);

        if (i == currentPage) {
            dots[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.active_dots));
        } else {
            dots[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_dots));
        }

        dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
    }
}

private int getItem(int i) {
    return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
}

private void launchHomeScreen() {
    preferenceUtil.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
    showBottomSheet();
    // startActivity(LoginActivity.class,null);
    // finish();
}

public void showBottomSheet() {
    BottomSheetFragment addPhotoBottomDialogFragment = new BottomSheetFragment();
    addPhotoBottomDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), BottomSheetFragment.TAG);
}

public void addTransparentStatusBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getWindow();
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    }
}

private void setupViewPager() {
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 3);

    Walkthrough1 walkthrough1 = new Walkthrough1();
    Walkthrough2 walkthrough2 = new Walkthrough2();
    Walkthrough3 walkthrough3 = new Walkthrough3();

    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(walkthrough1);
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(walkthrough2);
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(walkthrough3);

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            addBottomDots(position);

            mCurrentPage = position;

            // changing the next button text 'NEXT' / 'GOT IT'
            if (position == layouts.length - 1) {
                btn_next.setText(getString(R.string.start));
            } else {
                btn_next.setText(getString(R.string.next));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}

@OnClick(R.id.btn_next)
void nextPage() {

      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Top Padding : " + topPadding + " and bottom Padding " + bottomPadding,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    mCurrentPage = getItem(+1);

    if (mCurrentPage < layouts.length) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(mCurrentPage);
    } else {
        launchHomeScreen();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle system insets by yourself:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    val topPadding = view.rootWindowInsets.systemWindowInsetTop
    val bottomPadding = view.rootWindowInsets.systemWindowInsetBottom
}
```

But you get access to rootWindowInsets only when view is attached to window. It is safe to get rootWindowInsets in following callbacks:

```
view.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(...)
```

or

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(...)
```

Comment: I forget to add that you can't do it before view is attached to window. You can use callback, for example, view.addOnAttachStateChangeListener or  ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener

Comment: Also you can try view.post {}

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_walkthrough);
 view = relativeLayout.getRootView();
view.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener((v, insets) -> {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                topPadding = view.getRootWindowInsets().getSystemWindowInsetTop();
                bottomPadding = view.getRootWindowInsets().getSystemWindowInsetBottom();
            }
      return null;
        });
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.getRootView()' on a null object referen

Comment: Please, move view = relativeLayout.getRootView(); into your callback or use another view, at the moment you want access it relativeLayout.getRootView is null

Comment: Or just override onAttachedToWindow in your activity and move your code there)

Comment: @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        view = relativeLayout.getRootView();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            topPadding = view.getRootWindowInsets().getSystemWindowInsetTop();
            bottomPadding = view.getRootWindowInsets().getSystemWindowInsetBottom();
        }
    }
    
    this causes : android.view.View.getRootView() on a null object reference

Comment: Sorry, I can't help here without full code. Just try ti use view which not null.

Comment: Bro Full Code the above activity is onboarding WalkThroughActivity in which i am inflating fragments

Comment: Your view is null at ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view, ...), just replace view with relativeLayout

Comment: ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(relativeLayout, (OnApplyWindowInsetsListener) (v, insets) -> {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                topPadding = relativeLayout.getRootWindowInsets().getSystemWindowInsetTop();
                bottomPadding = relativeLayout.getRootWindowInsets().getSystemWindowInsetBottom();
            }
            return null;
        });
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.view.WindowInsets.isConsumed()' on a null object reference

Comment: You return null from the callback, just return insets

Comment: Thanks bro i got values and added those values to top and bottom padding to layout but still i did not got the desired result, My layout button and phone system button and overlapping now i can't access layout button, i will provide image

Comment: If it answered your question you can approve it and ask another one regarding layout issues.

Comment: I wanted lauoyt button above phone button

Comment: Layout button and phone button are overlapping

Answer (score 0):

`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`  only works for some layout parent and not all... it works for Coordinator layout and Constraint layouts.